# VirtualStringTree CellPaint

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Well, I have the following problem:

I've painted the tree cells in different colors depending on some boolean vars.
Example:

- isProcessService,
- isProcessInDebugger,
- isProcessService,
- isProcessElevated,
- isProcessNet,
- isProcessOwner,
- isProcessinJob,
- isProcessPacked,
- isProcessMarkedForDeletion,
- isProcessMarkedForCreation : Boolean;

So in BeforeCellPaint I'll paint the cells background color based on those booleans like:

```
procedure TMainForm.ProcessVstBeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
var
  NodeData: PProcessData;
begin
 if Node = nil then
    Exit;

  NodeData := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);

  if NodeData = nil then
    Exit;

  if (NodeData^.isProcessOwner) then
  begin
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $00AAFFFF;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(TargetCanvas.ClipRect);
  end;

  if (NodeData^.isProcessInDebugger) then
  begin
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $00E5A5A5;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(TargetCanvas.ClipRect);
  end;

    if (NodeData^.pProcessID = 0) or (NodeData^.pProcessID = 4) then
  begin
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $00FFCCAA;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(TargetCanvas.ClipRect);
  end;

  if (NodeData^.isProcessElevated) and not(NodeData^.isProcessInDebugger) then
  begin
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $0000AAFF;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(TargetCanvas.ClipRect);
  end;

  if (NodeData^isProcessService) and
    not (NodeData^.isProcessPacked) and
    not(NodeData^.isProcessNet) then
  begin
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $00FFFFCC;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(TargetCanvas.ClipRect);
  end;

  if (NodeData^.isProcessMarkedForDeletion) then
  begin
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $005D5DFF;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(TargetCanvas.ClipRect);
  end;

  if (NodeData^.isProcessMarkedForCreation) then
  begin
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $0061E15E;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(TargetCanvas.ClipRect);
  end;

  if (NodeData^.isProcessNet) then
  begin
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $005CE0BF;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(TargetCanvas.ClipRect);
  end;
end;
```

The question is:

How could I paint the cell green or red depending on a process is going to be created or deleted (let the color stay for at least one second and then switch back to its original value?)

I other words, a process is created paint the cell green wait a second and then switch back to the original color depending on: isProcessService, is ProcessOwner and so on...

The biggest Problem is I need this in a non blocking mode (I can not use sleep otherwise the tree will freeze too so the color change will not be noticed)

**If you still can not follow me, I'm trying to mimic the same behavior Process Explorer or Process Hacker does when a process is created or deleted. Both applications paints the cell background for those processes red or green for a second then switching back to the original color the cell had.**

Just for information, I'll get notified of process creation or deletion via wmi.

Comment: Use `CellRect`, not `TargetCanvas.ClipRect`.

Comment: How do you handle the changes in proccess list, do you constantly rebuild the tree or do you add/delete nodes as needed? BTW, the correct way to set cell's background color in VT is to use `BeforeItemErase` event (with `EraseAction := eaColor`), not `BeforeCellPaint`.

Comment: You're right got confused a litte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever a process is created, start a timer associated with that process with a timeout of 1s.  The `isProcessMarkedForCreation` is set to true and so the row is painted green.  When the timer fires the handler sets `isProcessMarkedForCreation` to false and forces a repaint of that row which removes the green highlight.  Now that the timer has done its work it should be deleted.  The exact same approach can be used for deletion.